# Impression region in ContentBlockByKey SSJS function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying to use the function "Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey()", but I don't quite understand what are parameter 2 and 3.
And in case of not having any value, I understand that you can't leave it to null.
I would be interested in using this function to always have a default value, since the first block will be dynamic and may not be available sometimes.
These are blocks that contain only text, no links or images.

```
<script runat="server">
 Platform.Load("Core","1.1.3");
 var content = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("Block_1","",false,"Block_default");
 Write(TreatAsContent(content));
</script>
```

Thanks

[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformContentContentBlockByKey.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see why the documentation can be confusing, so let me try and put some more explanation behind the parameters in this function call:

```
ContentBlockByKey(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

1. The first one, being mandatory, defines the content block you would like to load using SSJS. This should preferably exist.
2. Impression region name is useful, if you are loading the content block conditionally, meaning not all recipients of the email will be receiving it. Or there might be multiple blocks sent out to different recipients. Utilising Impression Region feature will allow you to keep track on who has received which content block, and whether they have clicked any of the links within. In your particular case, this click tracking will not be relevant as you write that no images or links will be present. [Here is a good guide](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/reporting/impression-tracking-in-marketing-cloud/) explaining Impression Regions in more details.
3. If a content block with the key defined in your function is not found, you could decide on not sending this email. Value of *true* raises an error and stops the call. I am not sure what the default behaviour is, if you don't provide any value here.
4. If your function fails to find the content block defined in the first parameter, you can define a fallback block in this parameter, which will be fetched instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and the guide. I will thoroughly check the "Impression Traking" issue. :)